# Parsing JSON object+array in Java

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to parse the following JSON:

```
{"city":{"id":2643743,"name":"London","coord":{"lon":-0.12574,"lat":51.50853},"country":"GB","population":0},"cod":"200","message":0.0456,"cnt":7,"list":[

    {"dt":1440504000,"temp":
        {"day":16.85,"min":14.23,"max":16.85,"night":14.23,"eve":16.32,"morn":16.85},
    "pressure":1013.06,"humidity":79,"weather":[
        {"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10d"}],
    "speed":7.36,"deg":172,"clouds":88,"rain":1.09},
    {"dt":1440504001,"temp":
        {"day":16.85,"min":10.03,"max":18.15,"night":14.23,"eve":16.32,"morn":16.85},
    "pressure":1013.06,"humidity":45,"weather":[
        {"id":501,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10d"}],
    "speed":15.46,"deg":172,"clouds":88,"rain":1.09},
    {"dt":1440504002,"temp":
        {"day":16.85,"min":4.73,"max":11.12,"night":14.23,"eve":16.32,"morn":16.85},
    "pressure":1013.06,"humidity":59,"weather":[
        {"id":502,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10d"}],
    "speed":17.12,"deg":172,"clouds":88,"rain":1.09}]}
```

The info I wanna parse is: "min", "max", "humidity" and "speed". As this is the first time I have to parse arrays, I don't know exactly how to parse this. After reading some forum threads I wrote the following code:

```
public void filtraOW7days(String contenidoOW) throws ParseException{ 
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    try{
        Object obj = parser.parse(contenidoOW);
        JSONObject jsonList = (JSONObject) obj;
        JSONArray list = (JSONArray) jsonList.get("list");
        Iterator<String> unitsIterator = list.iterator();
        int i = 0;
        while(unitsIterator.hasNext()){
            Object uJson = unitsIterator.next();
            JSONObject uj = (JSONObject) uJson;
            this.humOWaux[i] =  (long) uj.get("humidity");
            this.windOWaux[i] = (String) uj.get("speed");


            JSONArray slideContent = (JSONArray) uj.get("temp");
            Iterator c = slideContent.iterator();


            while (c.hasNext()) {
                JSONObject slide = (JSONObject) c.next();
                this.tmaxOWaux[i] =(String) slide.get("max"); 
                this.tminOWaux[i] = (String) slide.get("min"); 
            }


            i++;
        }

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}

Where the String contenidoOW is the JSON.This code gives me the following error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException at "this.humOWaux[i] =  (long)
>   uj.get("humidity");".

I don't understand why (at least I cannot see why), so can you please help me?

EDIT: I'm using org.json.simple and the declaration of the variables are:

`private String[] tminOWaux;
private String[] tmaxOWaux;
private long[] humOWaux;
private String[] windOWaux;`

Thanks for your time, really apreciate it!

Comment: What `JsonParser` are you using? Is it from jackson library?

Comment: Where do you initialise the `humOWaux` field? If that's `null` you'll get a NullPointerException trying to reference an index of it.

Comment: Please check the declaration for this.humOWaux[i], to  verify whether it has been initialized or not.

Comment: please post the `tmaxOWaux` declaration? and tell us wich json library are you using?

Comment: I'm using org.json.simple and the declaration of the variables are:

private String[] tminOWaux;
private String[] tmaxOWaux;
private long[] humOWaux;
private String[] windOWaux;

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Instead of writting String[] tminOWaux; I wrote String[] tminOWaux = new String[7]; and the error dissapears, but still not working. Now the following error appears: "org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONArray" at --> "JSONArray slideContent = (JSONArray) uj.get("temp");"

Comment: @catasturslykid That's because the "temp" property **isn't** an array. It's an object, as denoted by the curly braces (`{` and `}`).

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I see.. and how can I parse it? The same way as "hum" and "speed"?

Comment: @catasturslykid Pretty much. Just need to get a reference to the "temp" object, then access its properties.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I see... Sorry to bother you, but can you tell me how to reference to the "temp" object? I'm getting started with this... Thanks for your time, really appreciate it!

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I found it! I wrote: "JSONObject slideContent = (JSONObject) uj.get("temp");" and now it works. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

```
Long humidity=null; // long humidity=0;
if(uj.get("humidity")!=null){
  humidity=Long.valueOf(uj.get("humidity"))
}
```

Comment: Hello @seahawk. I'm using org.json.simple

Comment: @catasturslykid : the solution i provided...worked for you or not..?

Comment: @seahawk Your code won't compile - you can't initialise a variable of primitive `long` type to `null`.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist : thanks for pointing it. I often make this error while writing code. I have updated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I finally solved it. The final code is:

```
//Using org.json.simple
private double[] tminOWaux = new double[7];
private double[] tmaxOWaux = new double[7];
private long[] humOWaux = new long[7];
private double[] windOWaux = new double[7]; 
public void filtraOW7days(String contenidoOW) throws ParseException{ 
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    try{
        Object obj = parser.parse(contenidoOW);
        JSONObject jsonList = (JSONObject) obj;
        JSONArray list = (JSONArray) jsonList.get("list");
        Iterator<String> unitsIterator = list.iterator();
        int i = 0;
        while(unitsIterator.hasNext()){
            Object uJson = unitsIterator.next();
            JSONObject uj = (JSONObject) uJson;
            this.humOWaux[i] =  (long) uj.get("humidity");
            this.windOWaux[i] = (double) uj.get("speed");

            JSONObject slideContent = (JSONObject) uj.get("temp");
            this.tmaxOWaux[i] = (double) slideContent.get("max");
            this.tminOWaux[i] = (double) slideContent.get("min");

            i++;
        }

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Basically, the error was that I dind't initialize the variables properly. Also, I was trying to parse a JSONObject as a JSONArray.

Thanks guys for your help!